# Как получить спосок файлов из списка полных путей?

Tags: python, файлы, пути

Имеется список из путей вида:

```
['C:/f/f/f/fol/1.txt', 'C:/f/F/1.txt']
```

Вложенность пути всегда разная.

Как мне лучше всего получить имена файлов?

Сразу пришла идея перевернуть строку, найти вхождение первого слэша, обрезать строку и перевернуть обратно, но это же костыль какой-то.

Можно ли это как-то реализовать посредством регулярных выражений?

Comment: `'C:/f/f/f/fol/1.txt'.rpartition("/")[-1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), чтобы не зависеть от варианта написания пути и иметь *платформо-независимое* решение:

```
from pathlib import Path

paths = ['C:/f/f/f/fol/1.txt', r"c:\path\to\2.txt", "c:\\let's/have\\some/fun.txt"]
res = [Path(x).name for x in paths]
```

---

результат:

```
['1.txt', '2.txt', 'fun.txt']
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть два варианта. Один - разбиваем строку по знаку '/' и берем последнюю часть:

```
s.split('/')[-1]
```

Второй вариант, более правильный - использовать модуль os, чтобы программа адекватно работала на любых платформах (могут использоваться разные символы для разделения части пути - / или \):

```
import os
os.path.split('C:/f/f/f/fol/1.txt')[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно воспользоваться .split

```
_list = ['C:/f/f/f/fol/1.txt', 'C:/f/F/1.txt']

items = [item.split('/')[-1] for item in _list]
```

результат:
[1.txt, 1.txt]